# Angular JS ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm learning it independently.
I read about `ng-if` **[using the official AngularJS website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**.

I got an exercise which I need to scan a color, and if the color is **white** (`#fff` in hex), I should change the span's background-color to **black** (`#000` in hex).

This is what I've tried **[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/worinazi/1/edit)**.
I involved Javascript because I don't know how to deal with CSS on Angular and I think that's they reason why the code is not working as expected.

Sorry for being ignorant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) if you're going to do more angular development.

Comment: It ok that you post your code at jsbin, but if it is possible try to create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use inline JS (`onclick`) when you have `ng-click` (or at all, for that matter). I suggest you take a step back and make sure you understand what's going on, and not just put in random bits of code in hope they would give you what you want.

Here's an updated [demo](http://jsbin.com/worinazi/2).

First, I removed the `onClick`. then I changed the function to be included in the `scope` as that's the only way things you put in things like `ng-click` can find those functions. Last, I changed added a `backgroundColor` variable to be set to the desired color when the button is clicked, and changed the `style` attribute of the output element to have a `background-color` rather than `color` like you had.

Also, I don't see how `ng-if` has anything to do with this.